# Custom text cell color in tableview

Tags: javafx-8

I have this tableview data:

[image]

I want change the text color of last column cells following this rules:

- if row is selected -> default selection color
- if text is PENDING or WORKING and row not selected -> default text color
- if text is CANCELLED and row not selected -> red color
- if text is DONE and not row not selected -> green color

How can I get that? For selection I use:

```
tableview.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(false);  
tableview.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE);
```

I have tried:

```
lastCol.setCellFactory(col -> new TableCell<Work, StateEnum> () {
  @Override
  protected void updateItem (StateEnum item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);
    Paint textColor = null;
    if (this.isSelected()) // doesn't work, always is false
      textColor = getDefaultSelectionTextColor(); // how can I get this?
    else {
      if ((item.equals(StateEnum.PENDING) || 
         (item.equals(StateEnum.WORKING))
        textColor = getDefaultTextColor(); // how can I get this?
      else if (item.equals(StateEnum.CANCELLED))
        textColor = Color.RED;
      else
        textColor = Color.GREEN;
    }
    setTextFill(textColor);
  }
}
```

but, I don't know how get the default text colors and how know if cell row is selected. Maybe updateItem is not the most suitable method for do this? Can I do this with styles in css? I have read about pseudoclasses but I have no idea how can I use it for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could and should use CSS to style the text. `PseudoClass` would be the simplest way of changing, if certain selectors match the cell:

```
*final PseudoClass cancelled = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("cancelled");
final PseudoClass done = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("done");

lastCol.setCellFactory(col -> new TableCell<Work, StateEnum> () {
  @Override
  protected void updateItem (StateEnum item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);

    pseudoClassStateChanged(done, false);
    pseudoClassStateChanged(cancelled, false);

    if (empty || item == null) {
        setText("");
    } else {
        setText(item.toString());
        switch (item) {
            case CANCELLED:
                pseudoClassStateChanged(cancelled, true);
                break;
            case DONE:
                pseudoClassStateChanged(done, true);
                break;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

#### CSS stylesheet

```css
/* keep old style when selected */
.table-row-cell:selected .table-cell:cancelled,
.table-cell:selected:cancelled,
.table-row-cell:selected .table-cell:done,
.table-cell:selected:done {
    -fx-text-fill: -fx-text-background-color;
}

/* adjustment of color for unselected cases */

.table-cell:cancelled {
    -fx-text-fill: red;
}

.table-cell:done {
    -fx-text-fill: green;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm. But I don't understand your code: cancelled PseudoClass refers to ".table-cell:cancelled", ".table-row-cell:selected .table-cell:cancelled" or ".table-cell:selected:cancelled" css style?

Comment: @user1151816 A CSS selector can be composed of selectors based on different criteria. The same "selector part" may be used in different rules. A rule is applied to all nodes match the selector. If multiple rules assign the same property, the rule with the "most concrete" selector "wins". In this case all rules assign the same property. If neither the cell nor the corresponding row is selected, the bottom 2 rules apply (assuming done/canceled). If the cell/corresponding row is selected the first rule overwrites the other rules, because 2 pseudoclasses vs. 1 or addition of ancestor selector.

Comment: Ok, understood. One more question: in your solution you don't execute pseudoClassStateChanged(done, false) and pseudoClassStateChanged(cancelled, false). In almost all examples that I have seen in internet, people use them. In your case they aren't necessary? Why?

Comment: @user1151816 They are present (but they may be moved to a uncommon location): The 2nd and 3rd statements of the `updateItem` method do this, and later the pseudoclasses are added back, if needed...

Comment: Oh, sorry, I haven't see it. Thanks very much for your help.